# Find total number of results in mySQL query with offset+limit

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I'm doing a pagination feature using Codeigniter but I think this applies to PHP/mySQL coding in general.

I am retrieving directory listings using offset and limit depending on how many results I want per page. However to know the total number of pages required, I need to know (total number of results)/(limit). Right now I am thinking of running the SQL query a second time then count the number of rows required but without using LIMIT. But I think this seems to be a waste of computational resources.

Are there any better ways? Thanks!

EDIT: My SQL query uses WHERE as well to select all rows with a particular 'category_id'

Comment: So amazing!!! Thanks for the question, dont understand why it only got 23 upvotes. So fundamental question.

Comment: This question title is better because it came up first: "How to check if limit was used in mysql?" https://stackoverflow.com/q/28995579/1066234 (duplicate)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: This was deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17

Comment: And the proposed solution by MySQL: Simply use two queries, one with LIMIT one without, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: I looked at it the suggested post-MySQL 8 solution, and it sounds like a generally bad idea. I guess it would be alright if your main reason for using `LIMIT` was to page a result set that would be too large to show/keep in memory otherwise, and the query is otherwise very fast. In all other cases - such as improving slow queries - we are left with the solution of streaming the entire result set to the client and applying the limit there.

Answer (score 8):

> The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS()
>   function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a
>   future MySQL version. As a replacement, considering executing your
>   query with LIMIT, and then a second query with COUNT(*) and without
>   LIMIT to determine whether there are additional rows. For example,
>   instead of these queries:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Use these queries instead:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE id > 100;
```

> COUNT(*) is subject to certain optimizations. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
>   causes some optimizations to be disabled.

Comment: This seems like a good option to go without the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`

Answer (score 7):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE column = 'value'` will return the total number of records in a table matching that condition very quickly.

Database `SELECT` operations are usually "cheap" (resource-wise), so don't feel too bad about using them in a reasonable manner.

EDIT: Added `WHERE` after the OP mentioned that they need that feature.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that my SQL query uses WHERE as well to select all rows with a particular 'category_id'

Comment: nyx, wouldn't SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE condition still work?

Comment: "SELECT operations are usually cheap" - Not if you have a couple of millions of DB entries and no primary and no index. Be careful.

Comment: @Avatar in that case you should not have done the first query at all. That would also affect that one.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) requires invoking `FOUND_ROWS()` afterwards, if you wanted to fetch the total count **with** the results returned from your limit without having to invoke a second `SELECT`, I would use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) results derived from a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `category_id` = 9) t2 WHERE `category_id` = 9 LIMIT 50
```

**Note:** Every derived table must have its own alias, so be sure to name the joined table. In my example I used `t2`.

Comment: I like this specifically because it hits the db once, but was wondering if it would be more "expensive" than 2 `SELECT`s one being a simple `COUNT(*)` since it performs a `JOIN`.

Comment: This was deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 queries as below, One to fetch the data with limit and other to get the no of total matched rows.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 1000 LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 1000;
```

As described by [Mysql guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) , this is the most optimized way, and also **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** query modifier and **FOUND_ROWS()** function are **deprecated** as of MySQL 8.0.17

Answer (score 0):

as of final of 2021, why not:

```
SELECT 
t1.*, 
COUNT(t1.*) OVER (PARTITION BY RowCounter) as TotalRecords
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, 1 as RowCounter 
    FROM MyTable
) t1 
LIMIT 120,10
```

using a subquery with a column marking every row with the same value, will give us the possibility to count all of the same values of the the resulted column with [PARTITION BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) window function's group

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `table` WHERE `category_id` = 9
```

Gives you the number of rows for your specific category.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` is more performant because it won't need to check for NULL value exclusion