# Get total number of rows when using LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find total number of results in mySQL query with offset+limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928611/find-total-number-of-results-in-mysql-query-with-offsetlimit)

I have a very complex sql query which returns results that are paginated. The problem is to get the total row count before LIMIT I have to run the sql query twice. The first time without the limit clause to get the total row count. The sql query is really complex and I think they must be a better way of doing this without running the query twice.

Comment: You'll get the advices to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` soon, but the thing is that `COUNT(*)` with the same conditions is more efficient

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229218/what-is-mysql-version-of-rowcount

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928611/find-total-number-of-results-in-mysql-query-with-offsetlimit

Comment: @zerkms : why don't you provide your own answer then?

Comment: @static_rtti the comment contains enough information and does not need any further elaboration.

Answer (score 125):

Luckily since MySQL 4.0.0 you can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in your query which will tell MySQL to count total number of rows disregarding `LIMIT` clause. You still need to execute a second query in order to retrieve row count, but it’s a simple query and not as complex as your query which retrieved the data.
Usage is pretty simple. In you main query you need to add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option just after `SELECT` and in second query you need to use `FOUND_ROWS()` function to get total number of rows. Queries would look like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name, email FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The only limitation is that you must call second query immediately after the first one because `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` does not save number of rows anywhere.
Although this solution also requires two queries it’s much faster, as you execute the main query only once.
You can read more about [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#id2890708) in MySQL docs.

**EDIT:** You should note that in most cases running the query twice is actually faster than `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. see [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)

**EDIT 2019:**

> The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS() function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a future MySQL version.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

It's recommended to use `COUNT` instead

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE id > 100;
```

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is slower than running another query without limit as I understood:
http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Plus it does not work in subqueries

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is most definitely **not** slower in my case which is a somewhat complex query taking anywhere from 2 - 10 seconds. This is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Is there any concurrency concern here? What if another person ran another SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS between your SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and your FOUND_ROWS()? I'm using [node.js MySQL plugin](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), it allows multi query statements but I'm not sure are all these clauses executed in one transaction.

Comment: What if you just UNION the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS() as a dummy row to your query? Would this solve the concurrency issue @zipper is mentioning?

Comment: The problem with `COUNT` is this : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11692  , when there are multiple JOINS, the count may not return what is expected.