# Select and count rows in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, row

I am trying to find a way to select and count some rows in my database. I was checking the MySQL docs and this is what I came up with:

```
$query = "SELECT *, COUNT(*) as total WHERE IMAGE != '' AND CATEGORY = '$category' $limit";
```

But this outputs a single row when done... :(

Than I have tried:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM PRODUCTS WHERE IMAGE != '' AND CATEGORY = '$category') as x
        WHERE IMAGE != '' AND CATEGORY = '$category' $limit";
```

This works, however I don't really know if this will perform well, because of the two SELECT statements (lus I don't need 'as x', but without this the query fails).

Is there a better way?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results from your query?

Comment: It would be better if the code didn't appear to be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows), see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887266/get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit)

Comment: Oblig [Percona article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) reference.

Comment: thanks! Could someone please add the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS related solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `sub-query` but not sure about the performance should be executed only once since there is no correlation from outer table

```
SELECT *, (select COUNT(*) from PRODUCTS) as total
WHERE IMAGE != '' 
AND CATEGORY = '$category' $limit
```

Comment: thanks, but your query unfortunatelly gives NULL. :(