# MySQL and Pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, pagination, relational-database

Below is the table called `list`:

```
 Column Name   Data Type
   id             (Int)     
   user_one     (String)    
   user_two     (String)
```

I would like to scan for a user in `user_one` and `user_two` `column`.

In return I would like to get back the first 100 records and a flag that says there are more records.

Solution #1:

```
ALTER TABLE list ADD FULLTEXT KEY `full_name` (`user_one`,`user_two`);
SELECT * FROM list WHERE MATCH(user_one, user_two) AGAINST ('john');
```

I believe solution 1 will perform better, but I am not sure how to add a `limit` of 100 and get a `flag`.

Solution #2:

```
SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE "john" LIKE Concat(Concat('%',user_one),'%') 
OR "john" LIKE  Concat(Concat('%',user_two),'%')
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 50
```

I think solution #2 is slower, and I don't know what's the best way to add a `flag` if there are more than 100 records.

Last, if possible, I would like to minimize entire table scans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can get 101 Rows and only use 100. if your array bigger than 100 there must be more rows

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE MATCH(user_one, user_two) AGAINST ('john') LIMIT 101;
```

2) Use **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** in your query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM list WHERE MATCH(user_one, user_two) AGAINST ('john') LIMIT 100;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

[Get total number of rows when using LIMIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887266/get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit)

Comment: Thank you.  Do these stop scanning the `table` after 101/100 `records` are found?

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, you will get some random 101/100 rows.  And the second batch may overlap/skip.  [_More on pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).