# PHP PDO search with pagination

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I know this questions has really been asked before, though I stil ran into troubles even though had a lot of materials read. My problem is that I can't really handle search and pagination **at the same time**, because they work perfectly on their own. This part of the script is where the main logic is:

```
// Quantity of results per page
$limit = 5;

// Check if page has been clicked
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = 1;
} else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

// Initial offset, if page number wasn't specified than start from the very beginning
$starting_limit = ($page-1)*$limit;

// Check if search form has been submitted
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $searchTerm = $_GET['search'];
    $sql = "SELECT company.id, company.name, inn, ceo, city, phone
              FROM company
              LEFT JOIN address ON company.id = address.company_id
              LEFT JOIN contact ON company.id = contact.company_id
              WHERE
                MATCH (company.name, inn, ceo) AGAINST (:searchTerm)
                OR MATCH (city, street) AGAINST (:searchTerm)
                OR MATCH(contact.name, phone, email) AGAINST (:searchTerm)
                ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $starting_limit, $limit";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':searchTerm' => $searchTerm));
    // Count number of rows to make proper number of pages
    $total_results = $stmt->rowCount();
    $total_pages = ceil($total_results/$limit);
} else { // Basically else clause is similar to the search block except no search is being made
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM company";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Again count number of rows
    $total_results = $stmt->rowCount();
    $total_pages = ceil($total_results/$limit);
    // And then make a query
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
      SELECT company.id, company.name, company.inn,
            company.ceo, address.city, contact.phone
          FROM company
          LEFT JOIN address
          ON company.id = address.company_id
          LEFT JOIN contact
          ON company.id = contact.company_id
          ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $starting_limit, $limit");
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

This is pretty much self-explanatory (filling table with returned data):

```
<?php
       // Filling the result table with results
       while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
           echo "<tr><td scope='row'>" . $row['inn'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td><a href='company.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['ceo'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td></tr>";
       }
       ?>
```

And here is the pagination panel:

```
<?php
    // Debug information - test how many results and pages there actually were
    echo $total_results."\n";
    echo $total_pages;

    // Paginating part itself
    for ($page=1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++):?>

    <a href='<?php
        if (isset($searchTerm)) {
            echo "pagination_test.php?search=$searchTerm&page=$page";
        } else {
            echo "pagination_test.php?page=$page";
        } ?>' class="links"><?php  echo $page; ?>
    </a>

    <?php endfor; ?>
```

The problem here is that while pagination itself works perfectly as well as search, but when I combine search and page parameter, I get back only 5 records for **any** search query ever and the pagination only have 1 page, but I'm still able to go to a page manually and the resulsts are there and correct!

Please, help me figure out what the problem is. Not only that, I started to notice that code become quite sloppy and unmaintanable, I welcome any critique and code organisation/architecture advice on that cause I know something is wrong with this one :)

Comment: `$limit = 5;` What do you expect? Of course the result is only 5 rows long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total number of rows when using LIMIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887266/get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write separate query to get the total count of the result by search criteria with out limit

```
$sql = "SELECT company.id, company.name, inn, ceo, city, phone
          FROM company
          LEFT JOIN address ON company.id = address.company_id
          LEFT JOIN contact ON company.id = contact.company_id
          WHERE
            MATCH (company.name, inn, ceo) AGAINST (:searchTerm)
            OR MATCH (city, street) AGAINST (:searchTerm)
            OR MATCH(contact.name, phone, email) AGAINST (:searchTerm)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':searchTerm' => $searchTerm));

$total_results_without_limit = $stmt->rowCount();
$total_pages = ceil($total_results_without_limit/$limit);
```

Comment: Great many thanks! What do you think about my code? Should it be refactored? I think it's turning into a mess right now?