# How to check if limit was used in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In mysql query, I have something like I select and order, and use where clause, etc..., and finally I have `limit 10` for example. Something like this:

```
Select *
From employee
where fired=0
limit 10
```

The problem is, how do I know if limit was used and the result was truncated? Basically I want to know easily if there were more results that got cut off from `limit`. I don't want to do something like

```
Select (count *)
From employee
where fired=0
```

subtract

```
Select (count *)
From employee
where fired=0
limit 10
```

Is there a simple way for this? Perhaps, like you know how after you run an insert statement, you can get the id using php built in function `get_sql_id()` (something like that), is there a `sql_count_without_limit()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the found_rows function like this:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
-> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

For more information see [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: This function is deprecated. They suggest to use two seperate queries. One with `LIMIT` an one without `LIMIT`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 7):

You could do

```
Select *
From employee
where fired=0
limit 10+1
```

So that:

```
0-10 values returned: no limit was reached
11 values returned: Limit was reached
```

And then only use the first 10 values that are returned.

**update** Raymond's answer is waaaaay better than mine!

Comment: Throws this error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+1'".

Answer (score 2):

You can return the remaining rows as an column like below

```
SET @limit = 10;

SELECT *,
(SELECT count(*) from employee)- @limit as remaining
From employee
where fired=0
limit 10
```

Comment: Doesn't count(*) become at most 10?

Comment: no if total rows are 30 and you apply limit=10 the remaining will be 30-10 that is 20

Comment: This is also a cool answer, maybe better than Raymonds because I do one less php mysql query.

Comment: Actually, if I use this, then I would need to make two queries, one to get the results, and another one with mostly same code that is used just to get `remaining`. Is there a way to combine them? If not then I think Raymonds answer is more efficient.

Comment: @omega see if it works correctly for you in single query :)

Comment: I tried putting like `,count(*) as total` on my initial query which actually selects columns, but it gave an error about cannot count without group or something like that.