# Why does $stmt->num_rows count before MySQL LIMIT?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm executing a SQL Statement in PHP, using `LIMIT $start, $offset` to paginate results.

An unexpected hurdle, is `$stmt->num_rows` is returning all rows regardless of SQL `LIMIT`. Here is my code, just incase I haven't made a silly mistake:

```
$term = '%'.$search.'%'; // I have used htmlspecialchars() above
    $reclimit = 20;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $reclimit;
    $offset = ($page + 2) * $reclimit; // I want to get 60 results in total, or 3 pages of results.

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","db");

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title,description FROM content WHERE title LIKE ? LIMIT $start, $offset");

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $term);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $desc);

    $rowcount = $stmt->num_rows; // This will get all results, regardless of `LIMIT`
    $tpages = ceil($rowcount / $reclimit); // $rowcount returning incorrect integer messes up my pagination

    echo $start;
    echo $offset;
    echo $rowcount;
    echo $tpages; // Testing all variables to see which was the culprit

    $wcount = 0;
    $wmax = 20;

    while(($stmt->fetch()) and ($wcount < $wmax))
    {

        // Echoing HTML --snipped--

        $wcount++;
    }

    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();
    }
```

I can't see anything I've done incorrectly, and it seems strange `$rowcount` would return a value from all returned rows, regardless of `LIMIT` as the data returned has been limited before the sum has been called. Have I misunderstood something?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total number of rows when using LIMIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887266/get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928611/find-total-number-of-results-in-mysql-query-with-offsetlimit

Comment: What about the actual result? Do you have all the records fetched or only 60 records?

Comment: I cant get it to not work! I've had a play with your code and besides being able to blow it up with illegal $start and $offset values, it behaves. Only an empty search string gives me all rows as expected. Mysql 5.7.11, PHP 5.6.19 and PHP 7.04. i.e I get the expected rowcount values.

Comment: The syntax for limit is `LIMIT offset, row_count`, not `LIMIT start, end`. For (just) your first page you should give you your 60 rows though.

Comment: @EhsanT It only fetches 60 results, but counts all regardless of `Limit start,end`

Comment: have you tried moving this line: `$rowcount = $stmt->num_rows;` immediately after this line: `$stmt->store_result();` because according to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) _If you use mysqli_stmt_store_result(), mysqli_stmt_num_rows() may be called immediately._

Comment: @EhsanT it appears my `$offset` var doesn't have a value, despite `$start` having one. No idea why this is happening - thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It's weird that `$offset` variable does not have a value. You are setting it right after `$start`. And then it's more weird, even if because of `$offset` not having a value and you get the value of all records with `$stmt->num_rows` then you should also have all records in your `resultset` not only 60 records!

Comment: @EhsanT I managed to fix all of the issues and got it working correctly. I decided to hardcode `$offset` to 60 as I only want to fetch 60 results from the current `$start` - amongst other issues it's working now. Thanks for your replies, been very helpful!

Comment: :) great, have fun coding...