# How to count number of rows in MySQL table (PHP PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, count (tmdb_id),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

FROM tmdb_movies

JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

HAVING find_in_set('$category1', genres_name) AND find_in_set('$category2', genres_name) 

LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start"); 


     // Then fire it up
     $stmt->execute();

 // Pick up the result as an array
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Since i cannot calculate total number of rows which include `$category1` and `$category2` in the same code, I added this code before it.

```
$sql = "SELECT count(tmdb_id),group_concat(genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

 FROM `tmdb_movies` 

JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
HAVING find_in_set('$category1', genres_name) AND find_in_set('$category2', genres_name) "; 

$result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$totalrows = $result->rowCount();
echo $totalrows;
```

But `$totalrows` echo `3` here. But their a lot more rows than 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find total number of results in mySQL query with offset+limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928611/find-total-number-of-results-in-mysql-query-with-offsetlimit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overriding the $stmt after execute using fetchAll()

so instead try this

```
$stmt->execute();
 $totalrows = $stmt->rowCount(); 
 echo $totalrows;
 // Pick up the result as an array
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: It echo the movie title of the 1st row

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetchRow() in `

Comment: Here answer is 10, because Limit is 10.

Comment: so what you want? it will return according to limit, if you need all remove the limit from query

Comment: I cannot remove limit. I want to count all the rows in my database to make pagination system. 

So i need to make another select statement to count this without limit?

Comment: yes, for pagination just use select * from tablename; and then count the rows totaal then use it

Comment: I want to count only those rows which include $category1 and $category2 @exprator, see my code

Comment: so bro write a query like that just dont keep limit to it, means another sql query for pagination and do the count. thats all

Comment: I tried it but i have a problem with it also. Wait, i will update my question.

Comment: use rowCount instead of fetchColumn and see how many it returns

Comment: Done and Hmm...This is wired. It echo 9 rows more than total rows. I have 137 rows, it echo 146..

Comment: that you need to check with the sql. run the sql in phpmyadmin and check how many it returns

Answer (score 0):

Try rowCount() for count number of rows

```
$totalrows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: Here answer is 10, because Limit is 10.

Comment: Updated my question, see now

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, count (tmdb_id),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name) AS genres_name

FROM tmdb_movies

JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

HAVING find_in_set('$category1', genres_name) AND find_in_set('$category2', genres_name) 

LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start"); 


     // Then fire it up
     $stmt->execute();

 // Pick up the result as an array
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $conn->prepare('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as COUNT');
 $conn->execute();
 $count = $conn->fetchColumn();
 echo $count; //here's your total count
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::prepare() in `

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in ` . In my code $conn connects to the database

Comment: did you add the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in your original statement?

Comment: Now, i did...but `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute()` in line 149. This is line 149 ` $conn->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

```
    //This is the best answer ever to this questions since mysqli is deprecated     
    //this is the code to get the total number of rows
         $handler = new PDO(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD); $stmt = $handler->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalRows FROM table_name '); 
         $stmt->execute(); 
         $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
         $totalRows = $row['totalRows']; ?> 
         //this prints the total number of rows
        echo $totalRows;
```